# registering signals in Django results in "Apps aren't loaded yet." error

Tags: django, django-signals

I keep getting the error, when trying to import signals:

```
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

I can't understand this, b/c I've used the following pattern successfully when setting up a user profile in other apps:

**models.py:**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models

class UserProfile(models.Model):
  user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**signals.py:**

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from my_project.my_app.models import UserProfile

def post_save_user_hander(sender, *args, **kwargs):
     created = kwargs.get("created", False)
     instance = kwargs.get("instance", None)
     if created and instance:
         UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)


post_save.connect(
    post_save_user_hander, 
    sender=get_user_model(),
    dispatch_uid="post_save_user_handler",
)
```

**app.py:**

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'my_project.my_app'

    try:
        import my_project.my_app.signals  
    except ImportError:
        pass
```

According to [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.ready), `ready()` is called "as soon as the registry is fully populated".  Therefore, shouldn't the import of `UserProfile` succeed?  *Also*, the documentation states

> Although you can’t import models at the module-level where AppConfig
> classes are defined, you can import them in ready(), using either an
> import statement or get_model().

Therefore, including them at the top of **signals.py** which is itself imported in `ready()` should work, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to include signals in `AppConfig.ready` method.

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'my_project.my_app'

    def ready(self):
        import my_project.my_app.signals
```

From [docs on AppConfig.ready](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.ready)

> Subclasses can override this method to perform initialization tasks such as registering signals. It is called as soon as the registry is fully populated.

> If you’re registering model signals, you can refer to the sender by its string label instead of using the model class itself.

So, I suppose it's a common approach to include signals in  `AppConfig.ready` method.

Comment: Thanks.  I can't believe I did that!  It was just a copy-and-paste error.  I meant to include it in `ready()`, I just somehow missed out that line.